# RabbitTemplate to connect to RabbitMQ : getting - NOT_FOUND - no queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

I am new to spring and working on a cloud based application and trying to use RabbitTemplate and RabbitMQ.

I am able to store data to queue using.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, msg);
```

But when i am receiving the data from the same queue using

```
rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(QUEUE_NAME)
```

I am getting exception as:

> ERR Caused by: java.io.IOException
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicGet(ChannelN.java:985)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:625)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.basicGet(Unknown Source)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$4.doInRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:650)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$4.doInRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:646)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1045)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    ... 50 more
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR Caused by: **com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testqueue' in vhost '9cc1b4db-636e-4251-bb68-c7ed7f3be1d3', class-id=60, method-id=70)**
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    ... 60 more
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testqueue' in vhost '9cc1b4db-636e-4251-bb68-c7ed7f3be1d3', class-id=60, method-id=70)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:478)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:315)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
>   2016-09-13T11:15:21.38+0530 [App/0]      ERR    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:552)

My Code:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class RabbitConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory)connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory();

    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CHANNEL);

    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);

    return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("mq")
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "testqueue";

@RequestMapping(value = "/putinq/{msg}",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String storeMessage(@PathVariable("msg") String msg){
    String result = "";

    rabbitTemplate.setQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
    try {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, msg); // no exception
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Object object = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(QUEUE_NAME); // getting exception here
          System.out.println("Received: "+object);
        result = "success";
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

UPDATED RabbitConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class RabbitConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "testqueue";

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory)(connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory());
    System.out.println("------------------------ Rabbit mq template: " + cachingConnectionFactory.getCacheMode());
    System.out.println("------------------------ cachingConnectionFactory.toString(): " + cachingConnectionFactory.toString());
    cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CHANNEL);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(25);
    System.out.println("----------after set-------------- Rabbit mq template: " + cachingConnectionFactory.getCacheMode());
    System.out.println("------------------------ cachingConnectionFactory.toString(): " + cachingConnectionFactory.getChannelCacheSize());
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory);

    System.out.println("------------------------ Rabbit mq template: " + rabbitTemplate);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Queue myQueue() {
    System.out.println("--------------@@---------- creating queue: ");
    final boolean isDurable = true;
    final boolean isExclusive = false;
    final boolean autoDelete = false;
    return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, isDurable, isExclusive, autoDelete);
}


}
```

I tried searching this on the internet but still i am not able to resolve the issue, Struggling with this exception for long, any help is appreciated.

Got the solution!

```
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername("");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword("");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setVirtualHost("");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setHost("");
    cachingConnectionFactory.setPort(1);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(30);
    cachingConnectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(30000);

    RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(cachingConnectionFactory());
    Queue queue = new Queue(QUEUE_NAME);
    admin.declareQueue(queue);
    TopicExchange exchange = new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    admin.declareExchange(exchange);   admin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(QUEUE_NAME));
RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` to declare the queues/bindings - it automatically finds beans of those types and declares them on the broker when the connection is established.

If you use Spring Boot, it will automatically register a template and admin for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the queue itself in your configuration.

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue myQueue() {
    final boolean isDurable = true;
    final boolean isExclusive = false;
    final boolean autoDelete = false;
    return new org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue(QUEUE_NAME, isDurable, isExclusive, autoDelete);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the reply, I am still getting the same error: Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testqueue' in vhost '9cc1b4db-636e-4251-bb68-c7ed7f3be1d3', class-id=60, method-id=70)

Comment: Did you put it in your RabbitConfig and run it with profile cloud? (-Dspring.profiles.active=cloud as run argument or vm argument in most IDE)

Comment: Ya Jeff , i have pasted the updated RabbitConfig.java

Comment: Did you `Binding` your `Queue` and the `Exchange`?

Comment: What does it do if you delete the rabbitTemplate() method?

Comment: Hi Liping, i am doing 'cf push <app_name>', its automatic binding the RabbitMQ Instance with my spring app, i guess.  Do i need to explicity bind the queue and exchange ?

Comment: Make sure your queue is defined before your RabbitTemplate.

Comment: You need a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` to execute the declarations (queues/bindings) - it discovers the beans when the connection is established.

Answer (score 1):

You need binding your queue and the exchage, please try this RabbitmqConfig below

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitmqConfig  {
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "testqueue";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("spring-boot-exchange", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(QUEUE_NAME);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting same error: 
ERR Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'testqueue' in vhost '9cc1b4db-636e-4251-bb68-c7ed7f3be1d3', class-id=60, method-id=70)

Comment: sending to queue is not giving error but receiving is throwing the above exception

Comment: @RiteshKaushik please try to remove `rabbitTemplate.setQueue(QUEUE_NAME);` from your code.

Comment: Ya Liping, did that, no luck !  I Don't know why its still giving this error.

Comment: @RiteshKaushik can you go the the rabbitmq admin to check the queue/channel?

Comment: actually i followed the below example: github.com/PredixDev/predix-rabbitmq-cf . Also using my own cloud instance for RabbitMQ.

Comment: @RiteshKaushik the project is quite simple actually, I'm not sure but maybe you should to check the cf part.